# How to align fontawesome icon to the middle of a line (already tried the existing solutions)

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

i would like you to help me get this working:

html code:

```
        <div class="mainMenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Reviews <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Videos <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Forums</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

css code:

```
.mainMenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
}

.mainMenu ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.mainMenu li {
    float: left;
}

.mainMenu li a {
    line-height: 65px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

here's a link to a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/shock/r5rd3v86/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get precise control of the positioning by setting `position: relative` to the `i` element that contains the font-awesome icon.  Adjust the position using the `top` offset with a positive or negative value.

```css
.mainMenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.mainMenu ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.mainMenu li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.mainMenu li a {
    line-height: 65px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
}
.mainMenu li a i {
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="mainMenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Reviews <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Videos <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Forums</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set the vertical alignment of the icon, you can apply a minus margin to it:

```
.fa { 
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just tweak the positioning using a transform.

For example, with the following HTML:

```
<span class="fa fa-sort-asc"></span>
<span class="fa fa-sort-desc"></span>
```

Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
.fa-sort-asc {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.fa-sort-desc {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment so: 
Why you using `line-height: 65px;`? In jsfidle its like margin-top. try to use line-height equal to font-size and use `vertical-align:middle`

Comment: in the original code the menu has a container with a background.